# Excel file changing to read-only while in use

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, read-only

A user is able to open the file without it saying it is in read-only (it's not marked as read-only in the properties), but after they work on it and try to save it gives the read-only message ("We can't save 'filename.xlsx' because the file is read-only..." I've done some looking around, and tried turning off the preview pane and details pane, as well as disabling "Show pop-up description for folder and desktop items"

It's happening to multiple files, not just one. I haven't tried it on a word document, but the user said they didn't notice it.

I haven't been able to recreate the issue. They are running Excel 2013 on Windows 10. Any ideas?

Comment: If the file is on a network drive, a temporary connection issue will result in Excel knowing that the file is no longer readable. Unfortunately, it does not check if it is back accessible again, it just declares it read-only. You can simply save 'over' the file by using the same name.

Comment: It happens when excel files are stored on a shared location and being accessed by multiple user simultaneously, and sharing is not turned on in excel files. If file needs to be edited by multiple users at same time, make it shared through review tab - share option. If you open file in edit mode and other user opens same file in quick view mode, you will get same message.

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me, but apparently I was the multiple user.  I had a Word document open that was using the Excel spreadsheet as a database.  I had to open the spreadsheet to add a row of data, and was unable to save it because it was now "Read-Only".  I saved it with a different name, deleted the original file, then renamed the "different name" back to the original file name. A hassle, and creating potential for accidentally deleting a needed file.